# How to genrate the AES encryption value for the machinekey in C# 3.5

Tags: asp.net

I need to decrypt/encrypt based on the machine key. How can we generate the key and IV values? Is there any tool to do like this?

I am using .NET Framework 3.5

To tell what is required Ex:

```
//24 byte or 192 bit key and IV for AES
private static byte[] KEY_192 = { ... };
private static byte[] IV_192 = { ... };
```

Comment: Is that your real production key?

Comment: yes it will be the producation key

Comment: Then you probably want to change it now. Posting an encryption key on a public website defeats the point of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could *technically* hack this by leveraging the [FormAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.encrypt.aspx) class, it uses the same encryption under the hood  e.g.

```
var dataTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, String.Empty, DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1), true, "encrypt me!");
var encryptedData = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(dataTicket);
...
dataTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(encryptedData);
Console.WriteLine(dataTicket.UserData); // "encrypt me!"
```

A better solution would be to upgrade to .NET 4 and use the [MachineKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class directly.